# Selecting Multi Dropdown in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone help me solution for query

There are 2 dropdown. One dropdown contains all the "Countries" and 2nd dropdown contains all the "States". You have to fetch all the Values from "Country" Dropdow. Select the Country as "US" and have to Count,retrieve,verify all the "states"(in 2nd Dropdown) of Country("US"). I have Written the Code but can't complete

```
public class test {
static{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
int count=0, total=0;


driver.get("file:///C:/Users/usetr/Desktop/Country.html");

WebElement alllistBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Country"));


Select slt = new Select(alllistBox);
//Select Country India
slt.selectByVisibleText("India");

//Printing All country in dropdown and thier counts
List<WebElement> alloptions = slt.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : alloptions) {

System.out.println(option.getText());
count++;
}
System.out.println("Number of country present " + count);
```

Comment: similar to the manner you selected India, select india in first drop dowm. Then get the count from second drop down as you did for the first dropdown in the code...

Comment: What is your exact manual step? In the description you mentioned about `Count,retrieve,verify all the "states"`, Yes  we can `Count` and `retrieve`  but verify all the "states" with respect to what? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Assuming that you want to retrieve all the options from a DropDown, count and verify the selected option you can consider to use the following code block. This code block logs into `Facebook`, gets all the options from `Day` DropDown, then selects `28` as the date, verifies the date with the pre-defined value of `28` and prints out the result `Pass` or `Fail`:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Q45131741_DropDown_options 
{

    static
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String date_to_select = "28";
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        WebElement birthdayDay = driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
        Select selectDay = new Select(birthdayDay);
        List<WebElement> day_list = selectDay.getOptions();
        System.out.println("The options for this DropDown are : ");
        for (WebElement day:day_list)
        {
            System.out.println(day.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
        }
        selectDay.selectByVisibleText("28");
        String date_selected = selectDay.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
        System.out.println("Date selected is : "+date_selected);
        System.out.println("Date to be selected was : "+date_to_select);
        if(date_selected.contains(date_to_select))
        {
            System.out.println("Testcase Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Testcase Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.